# Select next child in array using c#

Tags: c#, arrays

I have an array,

```
 string [] myString = new string["2","1","3","2","1","2"];
```

And I want when I select one child I will get the next child value, That is to say, when I select the first one"2" , I will get the value of the second"1"...When I select the second one "1",I will get the value of the third one"3"...and so on...
I try to use index method, here is my code:

```
foreach (var index in myString){
int myindex = myString.indexOf(index);
}
```

Well, it is not the correct method...Any one know, how to do that? Thanks

Comment: Get the index of the element you're selecting and add 1 to it (make sure to check array bounds).

Comment: What do you mean by "select one child"?

Comment: What do you want to get for the last one?

Comment: If I understand correctly, you want to loop through the array and in the place of the 1st element, display the 2nd (in place of the 2nd display the 3rd) and so on? Why not just use a standard for loop and skip the first element `for (int i = 1; /* not 0*/ i < myString.Length; i++)`

Comment: "select one child", I mean the item inside the array...

Comment: The last one value is the first one...

Answer (score 6, accepted):

So I'm assuming that you want a function that will take the `string[]` and an `int` and return the next element (or the first element - if the `int` value indicates the last element). Something like this will do the trick ... (note I've just thrown the code in here without attempting to compile or testing so may need a tweak or two).

```
public string GetNextElement(string[] strArray, int index)
{
    if ((index > strArray.Length -1) || (index < 0))
       throw new Exception("Invalid index");

    else if (index == strArray.Length -1)
       index = 0;

    else
       index++;

    return strArray[index];
}
```

for a list you would have something like (assuming you always have a list of `string` objects - use `ToString()` otherwise)

```
    public string GetNextElement(IList<string> list, int index)
    {
        if ((index > list.Count - 1) || (index < 0))
            throw new Exception("Invalid index");

        else if (index == list.Count - 1)
            index = 0;

        else
            index++;

        return list[index];
    }
```

Comment: If it is a list , not an array,,,how does it works? I don't know the array length...

Comment: myList.Count would sort that for you.

Answer (score 4):

If I get you correctly this should do the trick:

```
string ChildValue(string[] myString, int which)
{
    if (which < myString.GetUpperBound(0))
        return myString[which + 1];
    else
        return myString[0];
}
```

You call this function like from wherever, like this (passing your string array and the desired index as arguments:

```
public void whatever()
{
    string[] myString = {"2", "1", "3", "2", "1", "2"};
    var selectedChildValue = ChildValue(myString, 3);
}
```

And as return value you will get the value of element 4.

Comment: if I get the array inside another function how can I get the array inside this ChildValue function? public void (){ string[] myString = {"2", "1", "3", "2", "1", "2"}; }

Comment: I edited my code to reflect this. Basically, you pass the string array as argument.

Comment: @Liu My answer accepts the array as a parameter to the function. Also, it will throw an error should the user enter an invalid index.

Comment: If it is a list , not an array,,,how does it works? I don't know the array length...

Comment: For the array, you do not need to know its length. "myString.GetUpperBound(0)" determines the highest index of any array you pass. For a List, you would use .Count, as amcdermott says. Just beware that Lists also start with index 0, therefor the "Count" value will be 1 too high and you'd need to use Count - 1.

Answer (score 2):

```
for( int i = 1; i <= myString.Length; i++ )
{
   string s = i == (myString.Length -1) ? myString[0]: myString[i] ;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

```
for( int i = 0; i < myString.Length - 1; ++i )
{
   string s = myString[i+1];
}
```

If I understood you correctly

Edit: added the +1 to the index within the loop

Comment: This will give the OP the 1st element to the second to last element. It seems (to me) from the OP like (s)he wants the 2nd through to the last element.

Comment: What is "selected" about this? This is just a loop.

Answer (score 1):

This will do if you want to get the first element for the last index:

```
string[] myString = new string[] { "2", "1", "3", "2", "1", "2" };
for (int i = 0; i < myString.Length; ++i)
{           
    string s = i == myString.Length - 1 ? myString[0] :  myString[i + 1];
    Console.WriteLine(s);
}
```